# Set selected value for symfony2 form with form type entity

Tags: symfony

I have an Entity named User in my symfony2 application. I have created a form in the controller using Create form builder.

My code in the controller is as follows:

```
$user = new User();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user);

        $resultForm = $form->add('username')
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl('usermanagement_create'))
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'PortalBundle\Entity\Roles',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new NotBlank(),
                    ),
                ))
                ->getForm()
        ;
```

I have to render the form, as selected some values as default for the field roles.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest to create the form into `Your/Bundle/Path/Form/YourFormType`?
That way your form could be used pretty much everywhere and if you need it, you can simply call it. Moreover, your controller will be much clean.

Writing about solution, you can proceed in different ways

1. Set [`empty_data`](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data) attribute
2. Set the roles explicitly into your object

### empty_data explaination

You need to inject (if you define a form as a service) or pass (if you define an external class for your form) or use (in your case) and entity manager to retrieve default choice object. I will show you a solution based onto your snippet

```
$em = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager();

$user = new User();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user);
$resultForm = $form
    ->add('username')
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('usermanagement_create'))
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('email')
    ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'PortalBundle\Entity\Roles',
        'empty_data' => $em->getReference("PortalBundle:Roles", //put here pk to retrieve default role)
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(),
        ),
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

If you need more than one role, write a query to return them and pass to `empty_data`

### Set the roles explicitly

```
$em = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager();

$user = new User();
$default_roles = $em
    ->getRepository("Path/To/Roles/Repo")
    ->findDefaults(); //maybe a method you need to implement
$user->setRoles($default_roles);
//and leave form code as is
```